# Dynamically assign a data source to a dynamically generated wpf combox

Tags: wpf, combobox

I am dynamically generating a combo-box in WPF, now, I want to populate the combo-box with dynamic values from the xaml resource file, the data to be populated in the combo-box exists in two different xaml resource files, I want to populate the combo-box based on a language selected by the user in the application. So, the "ItemsSource" property should be dynamic here based on the language selected

I am trying to use "SetResourceReference"

```
cmbCtrl = new ComboBox();
((ComboBox)cmbCtrl).SetResourceReference(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, "to be assigned");

cmbCtrl.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
cmbCtrl.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
cmbCtrl.ItemsSource = //should be dynamic based on the language selected
cmbCtrl.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Also, Would like your suggestions on how to put the data for populating in the combo-box to the xaml resource file

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Bind the ItemsSource to an `ObservableCollection<string>` and clear the list and fill it each time the language changes.

Comment: `Cmb.ItemsSource = this.FindResource(...) as SomeCollection`.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a class which will hold your `combobox` items as strings.

```
public class StringCollection : ObservableCollection<string> { }
```

Then in your resource file you can populate that list as a resource like this:

```
<local:StringCollection x:Key="Language1">
    <sys:String>Item 1</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Item 2</sys:String>
</local:stringCollection>

<local:StringCollection x:Key="Language2">
    <sys:String>Item 1</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Item 2</sys:String>
</local:stringCollection>
```

Once you have defined these resources you can easily populate your ComboBox by retrieving these resources in your code and assigning them to the Combo Box `ItemsSource` Property.